# Does $1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{2}{11}+...$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having a hard time figuring if the following series converges or diverges.
$$
1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{2}{11}\:+\:...
$$

I think that if I'll place the brackets in the right place I can figure what type of series are laying under. But I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: each group of three terms is of the form 
$$\frac{1}{3k-2}+\frac{1}{3k}-\frac{2}{3k+2}=\frac{18k-4}{27k^3-12k}.$$

Comment: It isn't obvious that grouping settles the problem.  If you group $1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots$ in pairs then the series appears to converge (though it doesn't really).

Comment: @lulu yes, that's because the individual terms have to tend to $0$ too, which they clearly do in this case.

Comment: If the sum of the first $3n$ terms tends to a limit, and the individual terms tend to $0$, then sum of the first $n$ terms tend to the same limit (this is easy to prove).

Comment: Yes...I agree.  My point (poorly expressed) was that it's a standard error to approach these things by focusing on groupings.  It works here, for the reason you give, but it always needs a side argument.

Comment: I understand the grouping. But I can't express it as a new series since this form is only valid for _odd_ $k$'s. Am I missing something?

Comment: @lulu is there a different way to approach this?

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld  Not that I see.  But I don't understand your objection to this method.  The partial sums are estimated and shown to approach a limit.  There's the technical point I mentioned but that has been addressed.

Comment: @lulu I have not objection, just not sure how to convert the form given by Lime to a provable convergent series.

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld you're right that you only need the odd $k$ terms. There are two ways round this: either substitute $k=2j+1$ or argue that since the term for every $k$ is positive, if the sum of all the terms converges then the sum of odd terms must converge.

Comment: But I can't conclude that if the grouping converges then without grouping it converges. Only if it diverges. In other words, proving that $(1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{5})+(\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{2}{11})\:+\:...$ converges doesn't mean that without brackets converges as well.